# Simple find/replace for all xlsm and xlsx files in a directory

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, find-and-replace

I have a directory with 20 spreadsheets. Some are xlsx and some are xlsm. I need to replace all instances of "foo", with "bar" in each sheet in each file. I'm using windows.

I'm on Windows so I don't think [this perl command line](http://lifehacker.com/5810026/quickly-find-and-replace-text-across-multiple-documents-via-the-command-line) would work.

I'm nervous about using [ReplaceText (formerly BKReplacem)](http://www.ecobyte.com/replacetext/) because of the big red warning ("Replace Text is no longer supported and has known problems with some Windows 7 installations.")

Tools like TextCrawler, TextPad, Notepad++, etc. don't look promising because they only seem to work with plain text files.

I tried IceTeaReplacer but it doesn't seem to work with .xlsm files.

The ExcelPipe 30-day trial version does the trick, but unfortunately isn't free.

How might one accomplish this, other than the obvious (but slow) solution of opening all 20 files and doing a find/replace?

Comment: Why not just use Excel?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Search text in multiple Excel files](http://superuser.com/questions/313187/search-text-in-multiple-excel-files/), [Searching for content in a large number of Excel files](http://superuser.com/questions/452980/searching-for-content-in-a-large-number-of-excel-files), [Search and replace tool that can handle multiple files and subfolders](http://superuser.com/questions/87544/search-and-replace-tool-that-can-handle-multiple-files-and-subfolders)

Comment: @techie007 Not sure, none of these address *replacing* text *in Excel*, do they?

Comment: @Daniel You're right. None of the questions were quite what I'm looking for but [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/313204/205203) might work for me. I'll try it out and update my question accordingly.

Comment: Darn! [IceTeaReplacer](http://www.icetear.com/en/menu/home/) doesn't seem to work on .xlsm files.

Comment: Surely, a sophisticated, professional tool like Excel must provide means of automation? http://vimeo.com/27983991